# lxc/lxd iptables ouput owner rule errors out with "Invalid argument."

Tags: iptables, lxc, owner

If I try to run the following command in my lxc/lxd Ubuntu 14.04 amd64 container:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

I get the following error message:

```
iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
```

...but `/var/log/dmesg` doesn't get any extra output.

I'm sure that iptables rule is valid because it works in the lxc/lxd host and in other machines.
The part that seems to be at fault is the owner part, i.e. if I run this:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

...it works fine.

This seems like a bug in lxc to me, but is there any way I can investigate it further?

**Edit 1**

I built iptables from source with debug flags and then traced through the execution. This led me to the `iptables-standalone.c` file, in which the:

```
int iptc_commit(struct xtc_handle *handle);
```

...function is returning an `EINVAL` error code. Problem is I can't track down the source for that function. It seems to be located in the `libip4tc.so` shared library, but I can't track down the source for that library.

If someone knows where the source, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

**Edit 2**

Refer to [this](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/860) lxc GitHub issue I created which paints more of a picture. I am going to give up, only because the work is too far-reaching for me to take on when I can just work around the issue by avoiding "owner" matched iptables rules in containers.

Comment: You should run dmesg command, not open file /var/log/dmesg

Comment: That does not yield any related error message(s) either. I was using `tail -f /var/log/dmesg` to make sure.

Comment: You can use command iptables --version to compare version between iptables inside lxc and iptables of the normal host. I think this error related to version of iptables

Comment: They are exactly the same version and the sha256sum of both `/sbin/xtables-multi` match. It's a problem with lxc, I'm going to build from source on the container and debug the problem myself, to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is set the "security.privileged" configuration of the container to "true", as it defaults to "false".

I.e. refer to [this](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/specs/configuration.md) and look for that "security.privileged" configuration.

I'm not exactly sure what changing this config does, so beware and research yourself, but I think it just grants the container more privileges with regard to controlling the shared kernel (shared between host and container).

Comment: The "this" link is not working